# Opening a Docx file from a returned output stream in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo, docx

I have a web app that takes in variables from the client and generates a docx file where it should then return that to the client.  My Java side works correctly and I can see a bunch of binary when I write the response to the console on the client side, however the client will not open this response in ms-word as I would like it to. I've set the ContentType to application/vnd.ms-word and the Content-Disposition to attachment and specified the filename, but no luck.
Anyone know what the problem might be?

```
dojo.xhrGet({
    url : "file.docx",
    content : {
        ...
    },
    load : function (response, ioArgs) {
        console.log("Successful xhr - Response:", response);
        window.open(response);
        return response;
    },
    error : function (response) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using dojo.io.iframe.send().  A problem I ran into is that the iframe was not resolving itself, blocking any future iframes from being executed.  I check for a previous iframe and call iframe.cancel() if one exists prior to calling dojo.io.iframe.send().